# Trying to connect environmental sensor via bluetooth in swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to connect a Kestrel 5500AG agriculture weather meter to an iOS via bluetooth using swift. I need to send temperature, wind speed and wind direction over to the app but I am having trouble connecting it first. If I search `withServices: nil` in the switch statement it will print out all of the bluetooth devices around me, including the device I want to connect, but when I search for an environmental sensor I get nothing.

This is what is printed for the device

```
<CBPeripheral: 0x282a25400, identifier = 35CA57D6-71A5-975C-E7F9-EADE3447BA32, name = AGRICULTR - 2403246, state = disconnected>

let kestrelServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x181A")

class ViewController: UIViewController {




    var manager:CBCentralManager!

    var kestrelPeripheral:CBPeripheral!
    var windDirectionCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A73")
    var windSpeedCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A72")
    var temperatureCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A20")
    var windSpeedCharacter = UUID(uuidString: "0000x2A72-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)


    }


}
extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {

        case .unknown:
            print("unknow")
        case .resetting:
            print("resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("off")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("on")
            manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [kestrelServiceCBUUID])
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }



    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if(peripheral.name != nil){
            print(peripheral)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `withServices: nil`. In `didDiscover peripheral`, print the advertisementData and the peripheral. It's the advertisementData of your target device doesn't contains the service `kestrelServiceCBUUID`, that's normal it wasn't finding it before. `withServices` filter on the base of advertised services.

Comment: this is what it prints <CBPeripheral: 0x283d583c0, identifier = 35CA57D6-71A5-975C-E7F9-EADE3447BA32, name = AGRICULTR - 2403246, state = disconnected>
["kCBAdvDataManufacturerData": <ea001300>, "kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs": <__NSArrayM 0x28020a2b0>(
03290000-EAB4-DEA1-B24E-44EC023874DB
)
, "kCBAdvDataIsConnectable": 1, "kCBAdvDataLocalName": AGRICULTR - 2403246]

Comment: Didn’t see it before, but at the start of your uuid you have a x, doesn’t seem to match.

Comment: so which one should be my CBUUID string?

Comment: From 0329 to 74DB in the log you put

Comment: that worked, thank you